# Paypal IPN no longer updating contributions

Tags: ipn

Contributions that are made via Paypal are no longer being updated from pending to complete. 
This happened suddenly on multiple sites. 
Is anyone else experiencing this?
I cannot find any errors in any logs. 
Any clue how to approach debugging this?

I am using CiviCRM 4.6.25 + Drupal 7.5x hosted by Pantheon

Comment: The civicrm_system_log table holds a record of incoming IPNS before they are processed - are there records there indicating that they came in?

Comment: Yes I see the IPN messages there. I don't see any error though

Comment: I compared the IPN messages in that table to the ones in from another site where the IPN is working fine and it all looks identical... any other ideas?

Comment: I looked at the log files and found this:
Jul 24 23:47:07  [info] Could not find an entry for invoice in POST
However lookin in the IPN log in the DB I do so an entry for invoice

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using this system, but I may have an explanation.  We use a custom coded donation system that expects PayPal to report back to us when there is a transaction.   On 7/26/17, 7/27, and 7/29 so far there have been no such transactions, on 7/28 we only received too.   The problem is confirmed to be a PayPal issue, and after fighting with them for 2 hours got a trouble ticket opened.  Log into PayPal and check your activity, then go to IPN (Instant Payment Notification Logs): https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history   If there is a problem communication with your site, it will show transactions that failed.  In my case, it clearly shows that PayPal is simply missing transaction entries under IPN that show up on the regular activity log.

Comment: The logs on PayPal look fine and the IPNs are definitely being received and logged in my site's db/